# Password won't work even after reset

Tags: password

My password in Ubuntu 20.04 isn't working all of a sudden.  I've tried and reset it with the recovery mode and it still dosent work. If I reboot it will take me to the desktop but I have no sudo ability if I log out of user and try to log back in. It doesn't work. control alt f3 asks for password and doesn't work either. I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: Which OS and version are you using?

Comment: Ive checked and iam using the correct keyboard layout i even went and just typed out my password and it was correct.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you edit your question to outline exactly what steps you take while "trying to reset it with recovery mode"? That will help people to narrow down the issue for you faster.